# POST data not coming in controller codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am posting a form with some data but I am getting empty POST array. The form is

```
<form name="opening-statistics" action ="<?php echo base_url()?>statistic/openings">
   <select name="titles" multiple="multiple">
       <?php foreach($titles as $title) { ?> 
          <option value="<?php echo $title['idtitles']?>"><?php echo $title['title']?></option>
       <?php } ?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

In my controller I have

```
 public function openings(){
    $data['boxes'] = $this->Statistic_model->getBoxes();
    $data['titles'] = $this->Statistic_model->getTitles();
    if($this->input->post()){
        echo 'I am here';
        $form = $this->input->post();
        var_dump($form);
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo 'I am here';
        $this->load->view('statistic/openings-statistics', $data);
    }
}
```

In my routes I have

```
$route['statistic/openings-statistics'] = 'statistic/openings';
```

It always come to the else statement

Anyone can tell me the reason ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add `method="POST"` to the form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catching the POST like this:

```
 public function openings(){
    $data['boxes'] = $this->Statistic_model->getBoxes();
    $data['titles'] = $this->Statistic_model->getTitles();
    if($_POST){
        echo 'I am here';
        $form = $this->input->post();
        var_dump($form);
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo 'I am here';
        $this->load->view('statistic/openings-statistics', $data);
    }
}
```

And Yes CI does have:

```
$this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST items with XSS filter 
$this->input->post(); // returns all POST items without XSS filter
```

Comment: I get the data now but i have one multiselect in my form I am getting single record in that

Comment: What does $this->input->post('titles') give you ?

Comment: The value of the last option selected

Comment: Please refer to CI Guide (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) search for form_multiselect(), there is an explanation on how to get the values

Comment: I am not using form helper :(

Comment: change name="titles"  to name="titles[]"